# 502 bad gateway error PhpStorm

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I created a new project in PhpStorm and my all php files were running successfully. But suddenly it started showing 502 bad gateway error. I am using PhpStorm 9.0 and xampp server using port no 80 and 443.
How can I fix it.

Comment: If you are using XAMPP then I do not see how PhpStorm can affect this... Screenshots please (browser with URL visible).

Comment: http://localhost:63342/NewWorld/test1.php     is the link and the error is 502 Bad Gatway phpstrom9.0. There is nothing else.

Comment: You are NOT using XAMPP -- it's PhpStorm's simple built-in server in action (look at URL -- `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/path/in/the/project`). IDE uses such built-in server when you use `Open in Browser` action and have no Deployment entry configured (where you can specify your correct XAMPP URL to be used)

Comment: To "fix" it -- go to `Settings (Preferences on Mac)` and search for "Deployment"; then create deployment entry, configure it and mark it as Default for this project. Or just do not use `Open in Browser` action and always use/type right URL in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it worked just created the project again and selected the interpreter again.

Answer (score 0):

You must install php-cgi on your server.

For more information you can see this link:

http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2011/07/apache-use-both-php-module-and-php-cgi.html

Comment: Can you explain that further? Which server are you talking about? As far as I see from the comment section, the OP uses the server provided by PhpStorm itself

Comment: Had this issue after switching to php8.2 - Installing this package helped. Now I no longer have the 502 error using phpstorms webserver
`apt-get install php8.2-cgi`
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found some solutions to this:

- Backup your project and uninstall XAMPP, then install it back.
- Restart the services that are running in XAMPP.
- Stop the services that are running in XAMPP and close it completely, then start it again.
- Restart PHPStorm.
- Some PHP codes are generating the error. Try to find them, comment them out and see if it works.